# Fetch files from folder

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have somes files in a folder. I want to fetch the files from that folder and convert each file to an object of binary stream and store in a collection. And from the collection, I want to retrieve each binary stream objects. How is it possible using ASP.Net with c# ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wish to have it stored in a MemoryStream you could try

```
List<MemoryStream> list = new List<MemoryStream>();
string[] fileNames = Directory.GetFiles("Path");
for (int iFile = 0; iFile < fileNames.Length; iFile++)
{
    using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(fileNames[iFile], FileMode.Open))
    {
        byte[] b = new byte[fs.Length];
        fs.Read(b, 0, (int)fs.Length);
        list.Add(new MemoryStream(b));
    }
}
```

Or even use a Dictionary if you wish to keep the file names as keys

```
Dictionary<string, MemoryStream> files = new Dictionary<string, MemoryStream>();
string[] fileNames = Directory.GetFiles("Path");
for (int iFile = 0; iFile < fileNames.Length; iFile++)
{
    using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(fileNames[iFile], FileMode.Open))
    {
        byte[] b = new byte[fs.Length];
        fs.Read(b, 0, (int)fs.Length);
        files.Add(Path.GetFileName(fileNames[iFile]), new MemoryStream(b));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

It can be as simply as this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;

List<FileStream> files = new List<FileStream>();
foreach (string file in Directory.GetFiles("yourPath"))
{
    files.Add(new FileStream(file, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite));
}
```

But overall, storing `FileStream`s like this does not sound like a good idea and does beg for trouble. Filehandles are a limited resource in any operating system, so hocking them is not very nice nore clever. You would be better off accessing the files as needed instead of simply keeping them open at a whim.

So basically storing only the paths and accessing the files as needed might be a better option.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;

List<String> files = new List<String>();
foreach (string file in Directory.GetFiles("yourPath"))
{
    files.Add(file);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using [DirectoryInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directoryinfo.aspx) and [FileInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.aspx) classes.  Here is some code that should hopefully do what you need:

```
System.IO.DirectoryInfo dir = new System.IO.DirectoryInfo(@"C:\TempDir\");
if (dir.Exists)
{
    foreach (System.IO.FileInfo fi in dir.GetFiles())
    {
        System.IO.StreamReader sr = new System.IO.StreamReader(fi.OpenRead());
        // do what you will....
        sr.Close();
    }
}
```