# Files to binary stream

Tags: c#

I want to fetch the files from the folder and convert to binary stream. How is it possible using ASP.Net with C# ?

Comment: what do you meant by 'binary stream'?

Comment: And which part are you stuck on? Post your code so far.

Comment: Isn't this the same as you asked in one of your other questions?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2243064/fetch-files-from-folder

Comment: -1 for duplicating your own question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `FileStream` will do the job:

```
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
{
    // work with fs
}
```